# React Hooks - Is this a pattern? (exposition of available methods and protection against mistakes)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have the following hook (in my RN app), which exposes 4 methods, each of them communicates with an external page. I intend to ensure the simplicity with which this action is carried out, in addition to saving possible errors by introducing typos.

This is the code:

```js
export default function useOpenPolicyPage(
  {
    onSuccess,
    onError,
  } = {}
) {
  const {
    result,
    error,
    openWebsite,
  } = useOpenWebsite({ onSuccess, onError });

  /**
   * Opens our community guidelines.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>} An empty promise.
   */
  const openCommunityGuidelines = () =>
    openWebsite(POLICY_PAGES.communityGuidelines, false);

  /**
   * Opens our legal notice.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>} An empty promise.
   */
  const openLegalNotice = () =>
    openWebsite(POLICY_PAGES.legalNotice, false);

  /**
   * Opens our privacy policy.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>} An empty promise.
   */
  const openPrivacyPolicy = () =>
    openWebsite(POLICY_PAGES.privacyPolicy, false);

  /**
   * Opens our cookies policy.
   *
   * @returns {Promise<void>} An empty promise.
   */
  const openCookiesPolicy = () =>
    openWebsite(POLICY_PAGES.cookiesPolicy, false);

  return {
    result,
    error,
    openCommunityGuidelines,
    openLegalNotice,
    openPrivacyPolicy,
    openCookiesPolicy,
  };
};
```

On the one hand, this technique caught my attention, since it would be enough to do the following to open a page:

```
const { displayError } = useErrorHandler();

const { openPrivacyPolicy } = useOpenPolicyPage({
  onError: displayError,
});

return (
  <Text onPress={openPrivacyPolicy}>
    Open our Privacy Policy!
  </Text>
);
```

But, on the other hand, I see that it is unnecessary and we could improve the performance by avoiding the creation of 4 extra functions... just doing:

```js
const { displayError } = useErrorHandler();

const {
  openWebsite,
} = useOpenWebsite({ onError: displayError });

const handleOnPress = () => {
  openWebsite(POLICY_PAGES.privacyPolicy, false);
};

return (
  <Text onPress={handleOnPress}>
    Open our Privacy Policy!
  </Text>
);
```

Still, I think the first solution is better, since in a large code base, it is possible that some teammate might miss using the constant or passing the argument `false`, which is a technical requirement and indicates that the website visited is not sensitive, but a trusted source.

Is the first example a pattern?

Comment: Creating 4 functions doesn't create a performance issue

Comment: Performance optimizations should be applied to areas where you measured an actual performance problem